Is machine learning deployment part of the job scope for a data scientist?
I applied for a (Supposedly) data scientist role.
I'm surprised that part of my job scope involves deployment machine learning models to production/cloud.
I would have thought isn't that the role of a data engineer? A data scientist role is to analyse datasets, coming out with insights and to research on machine learning algorithms.
I'm surprised that they also expected me to know how to deploy models on cloud as a data scientist. Is deploying models part of the usual job scope for a data scientist? Or did the company mix up the roles between a data scientist and a data engineer?

Yes. No. Maybe. It all depends on how the hiring manager / team perceives the role for which they are hiring you. What scope of work was discussed during the initial communication process?

Downvote is not mine. But get over it. When you are employed, you work as a team. Within reason, you do what the boss wants. The jobs are related, why is it an issue?

Does the company has someone else working as a "data engineer"?

Yes there is surprisingly

I've seen it a lot. DS is a broad field. Think about it this way: would you rather the DS and DE employ the model as a team? I recommend moving this to thew data science stack exchange

I'm an engineer myself yet I've done technician work like hooking up wires and circuit board repairs. I've also had to manage manufacturing operations. These are not typical engineering roles and responsibilities but when the job requires it, I can do it. Do you suspect that your manager is giving you unreasonable tasks that are outside of the realm of your capabilities? If so, have you talked to them about it?

Job titles are not carved in diamond and are not religious dogma. Often they are just a best fit for all the tasks which are assigned to the person holding that title.
Where I work data scientists are in charge of both developing machine learning algorithms/tools and rolling them out to the end users.
Apparently also for your case under the cap of "data scientist" there is the task of deployment to production. It's nothing out of the ordinary.
And don't forget that skills can still be learned also while on the job.

Well I already have all the skillset needed for that data scientist job except for model deployment, which I feel is a waste because the job requires model deployment too.

@HuiYing if you think you already have all the skills you will need for the rest of your career then you aren't suited for a career in cutting edge computer science. Sorry. You will need to constantly learn things until you retire, and in a few years many things you know now will be oboslete.


I'm surprised that they also expected me to know how to deploy models
on cloud as a data scientist. Is deploying models part of the usual
job scope for a data scientist? Or did the company mix up the roles
between a data scientist and a data engineer?
I would have thought isn't that the role of a data engineer? A data
scientist role is to analyse datasets, coming out with insights and to
research on machine learning algorithms.

If the company/project is small enough they will sometimes combine multiple titles into one.
Of course titles are meaningless outside the company.
If you don't have all the required skills then your odds of being hired aren't good. If the one skill you are missing isn't on the required skills, but only in the nice-to-have category you might be fine.  Just expect that they will require you to do those nice-to-have related tasks, and they will want you to learn how to do them.
Sometimes the nice-to-have list comes from a boilerplate, ot they were the "other tasks as assigned" that the provisos person on the team did.
